# cs240: the extra 150 MB used by recDir under two similar circumstances

Tags: haskell, memory, lazy-evaluation

I'm going through the slides of [Functional Systems in Haskell](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/16wi-cs240h/slides/iteratee-slides.html#(11)). In that lecture, there is a function defined `recDir2` which uses `unsafeInterleaveIO` to list all the files in a directory recursively:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as L

recDir2 :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
recDir2 dir = do
  ds <- openDirStream dir
  let protect m = m `onException` closeDirStream ds

      nextName = unsafeInterleaveIO $
                 protect (readDirStream ds) >>= checkName

      checkName "" = closeDirStream ds >> return []
      checkName "." = nextName
      checkName ".." = nextName
      checkName name = getSymbolicLinkStatus path >>= checkStat path
          where path = dir </> name

      checkStat path stat
          | isRegularFile stat = liftM (path :) nextName
          | isDirectory stat =
              liftM2 (++) (protect $ recDir2 path) nextName
          | otherwise = nextName

  nextName
```

Where

```
readFiles :: [FilePath] -> IO L.ByteString
readFiles [] = return L.empty
readFiles (f:fs) = liftM2 L.append (L.readFile f)
                   (unsafeInterleaveIO $ readFiles fs)
```

This function is used later in two seemingly equal situations:

```
*Main> recDir2 "/usr/include" >>= readFiles >>= print . L.length

*Main> x <- recDir2 "/usr/include" >>= readFiles
*Main> L.length x
```

However in the slides it is stated that the second case uses an extra 150 MB, but I fail to see the reasons why. What is causing this allegedly extra memory usage?

Comment: My guess: the latter can't garbage-collect `x` as it's consumed. What is `L` and `readFiles`? It's kind of hard to reliably check such a guess without knowing the code.

Comment: I added the definitions for `L` and `readFiles`. In the second case is there something to collect? Since the list in `readFiles` is constructed as needed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare this to:

```
> let xs = [1..999999999]
> length xs
```

and

```
> length [1..999999999]
```

In the second case, the garbage collector can clean up the list as it's being consumed, so you use up very little memory. But in the first case, you still hold a reference to `xs`, and you might type in `xs !! 555` at any time. So the garbage collector must keep the entirety of `xs` in memory for you.

Likewise in your example, one version has a reference to `x` that might be reused later, and so the contents of `x` must be preserved.

Comment: You might want to point out that this is in GHCI. In a GHC program, the former would be optimized to the latter variant.